# How to create a django app that lets you type in small python programs, execute the code and show the result?

Tags: python, django

The app should enable the user to type in small python programs.When click Run the code is executed and output is delivered to the user

Comment: Well this could be done. you just need to send over the text over to server side, compile the code and execute in a "restricted" environment. Otherwise "user" can write a piece of code to wipe out data in database and remove directories etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sphere Engine as a compiler and execute any code submitted from client side it supports more than 60 Languages and have very good sets of Api which are very easy to Integrate with any website. Ideone ,Codechef and many more are using it. you can try it